# Character encoding in Safari Mobile

Tags: iphone, safari, encoding

I've developped a website using JSF, which is accessed by Safari mobile running on Iphone 5C.
Most of the Iphones behave correctly, send the text encoded as it should, but on one of them, text is badly encoded.
Exemple: "Début" is written "DÃ©but" (it's french)
I suspect one of the user changed the settings on the Iphone.
What setting could it be, and how can you change it back ?

EDIT:
The website is rendered correctly, the problem arise when the user type text in a textbox and submit it to the server.

Comment: I have never heard of any way for users to change encodings in iOS (unless perhaps switching the system language might do that in some cases).

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing the Ã©?  This is just correct UTF-8 é being read as if it were iso-8859-1 or Win 1252.

Comment: I see it that way on the website after encoding, and also in the database with a client like Toad

Answer (score 2):

You could set the header to display UTF-8. The user might have his location settings set differently.

HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

PHP:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```